# Создание RAID 1 (зеркало) из 2 дисков на запущенной ОС

Tags: raid

Есть CentOS 6 на диске 1 Tb, нужно добавить ещё 1 диск 1 Tb диск и сделать из 2 дисков RAID 1 не прерывая работы системы на долго. Как лучше это сделать? Говорят что можно из текущего диска прям на лету сделать это, но мне кажется переразметка диска под RAID 1 сломается текущую разметку диска. Так ли это и если так какой путь лучше? Спасибо.

Comment: Может система случайно или специально на LVM стоит?

Comment: На LVM как раз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, вам повезло с тем что система стоит на `LVM`, это сильно упрощает процедуру и позволяет мигрировать на `raid` вообще без простоя.

Только одно маленькое "но" - необходимо откуда-то достать 1-2 мегабайта не размеченного пространства на PV - это место необходимо для суперблока raid.

Сделайте (всё от рута)

```
pvdisplay
```

Если есть хоть один `Free PE` то всё должно получиться. По идее должно получиться и если есть `not usable` область хотя бы в 1 или 2 мегабайта при дисках равной ёмкости. Предположим что место оказалось и приступаем к миграции:

Для начала с использованием любимой (любой, `fdisk`, `parted`, что угодно) утилиты разметки диска создаём желаемую разметку диска, например как имеющемся диске. Предположим, что это `/dev/sdb1` для `/boot` и `/dev/sdb2` под данные.

Далее создаём пару массивов `raid1` в изначально деградировавшем виде:

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 -l 1 -n 2 missing /dev/sdb1
mdadm --create /dev/md1 -l 1 -n 2 missing /dev/sdb2
```

(вообще возможно `grub` уже умеет загружаться с `lvm` поверх `md`, давно не пробовал)

Затем инициализируем массив с данными как новый том `LVM`:

```
pvinit /dev/md2
```

Расширим используемое пространство на новый диск:

```
vgextend имя_группы_томов /dev/md2
```

Имя группы томов - это было `VG Name` в `pvdisplay`

Теперь основной фокус: переносим данные с имеющегося одиночного диска на новый массив:

```
pvmove /dev/sda2 /dev/md2
```

Запускать стоит в `screen` или `tmux`, штука очень длительная т.к. работает на блочном уровне и будет копировать всю ёмкость `Allocated PE`. Зато отчитывается о проценте выполнения.

Когда, вероятно спустя несколько часов, команда завершится, необходимо выполнить вновь `pvdisplay`. Вы увидите два `Physical volume`, старый `/dev/sdb2` в этом примере должен быть с `Allocated PE` равным 0. Новый соответственно чем-то занятый. Если это не так - то надо уменьшать какой-то логический том, о чём в конце ещё напишу.

Итак, старый физический диск теперь не содержит данных в LVM и его можно из группы томов удалить:

```
 vgreduce имя_группы_томов /dev/sda2
 pvremove /dev/sda2
```

Теперь данные уже расположены на RAID1 и осталось добавить диск в этот массив:

```
 mdadm --manage /dev/md1 --add /dev/sda2
```

За фоновым процессом перестроения массива можно наблюдать в `cat /proc/mdstat`

Осталось перенести `/boot` раздел. Но эта такая несложная вещь, которую можно считать доступной только на чтение почти всегда. Поэтому подготовим новую файловую систему

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/md0
mount /dev/md0 /mnt/
rsync -av /boot/ /mnt/
umount /mnt
umount /boot
mount /dev/md0 /boot
```

Я думаю создание файловой системы, монтирование и перенос содержимого через `rsync` удивления не вызовет.

Затем необходимо добавить второй раздел в массиву с загрузчиком

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sda1
grub-install /dev/sda1
grub-install /dev/sdb1
```

Не забыть поправить `/etc/fstab` т.к. `/boot` изменили. А вот корень и другие файловые системы остались где были со старыми `UUID` и именами.

Теперь создадим файл конфигурации `mdadm` (вообще не обязательно, но должно гарантировать что система не будет переименовывать массивы при загрузке)

```
echo "DEVICE partitions" > /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
mdadm --detail --scan --verbose | awk '/ARRAY/ {print}' >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

И надо обновить initramfs через `update-initramfs`.

Когда массивы закончат синхронизацию можно перезагрузиться для проверки.

PS: весьма советую сначала проверить на виртуалке для своего дистрибьютива. Я мог случайно о чём-нибудь забыть упомянуть, давно уже так не извращался.

---

Если не повезло и не хватает места на диске. Необходимо от любого логического тома LVM отпилить необходимый кусочек. Или может быть стоило новый `/boot` чуток поменьше, кстати.

Необходимо сначала уменьшить размер файловой системы (зависит от того, какая именно это файловая система, например XFS в принципе уменьшаться не может, а многие другие требуют быть отмонтированными для уменьшения). Рекомендую уменьшить размер файловой системы побольше, чем требуется, чтобы случайно не обрезать используемые блоки - у `lvreduce` нет проверки на размер файловой системы, не тот уровень.

Затем уменьшить размер логического тома (в примере на 1гб уменьшается)

```
lvreduce -L-1G /dev/имя_группы_томов/уменьшаемый_логический_диск
```

Comment: СПасибо! Сделал, почти по вашей рекомендации.