# Software RAID в Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid

Был сервер с 1 HDD на 500 Gb. Установлена Ubuntu Server 18.04. Сейчас добавлен ещё 1 HDD на 500 Gb. Как сделать Software RAID 1 без переустановки ОС?

```
root@NLDW2-AZ5:~# lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME     SIZE FSTYPE TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda    465.8G        disk
|-sda1   381M ext4   part /boot
|-sda2   458G ext4   part /
|-sda3     1K        part
|-sda5     1M        part
`-sda6   7.5G swap   part [SWAP]
sdb    465.8G        disk
|-sdb1   976M        part
|-sdb2   7.6G        part
`-sdb3 457.2G        part
root@NLDW2-AZ5:~#
```

sda - старый диск, sdb - новый, его можно зачистить.

Comment: Зависит от того, что на дисках сейчас и какого рода raid массив хочешь получить в итоге...

Comment: Сделать RAID1 - т.е. зеркало.
<code>
    root@NLDW2-AZ5:~# lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT
    NAME     SIZE FSTYPE TYPE MOUNTPOINT
    sda    465.8G        disk
    |-sda1   381M ext4   part /boot
    |-sda2   458G ext4   part /
    |-sda3     1K        part
    |-sda5     1M        part
    `-sda6   7.5G swap   part [SWAP]
    sdb    465.8G        disk
    |-sdb1   976M        part
    |-sdb2   7.6G        part
    `-sdb3 457.2G        part
    root@NLDW2-AZ5:~#
</code>
sda - старый диск, sdb - новый, его можно зачистить.

Comment: RAID можно сделать аппаратный, нативный (mdadm), LVM, в особо упоротых случаях btrfs или zfs... но, судя по текущему состорянию, интересует нативный через `mdadm`... ЗЫ: данные стоит добавлять прямо в вопрос, нажав [edit].

Comment: Да, получилось криво. Добавил данные в вопрос. Интересует mdadm.

Comment: Если система стоит на LVM - более релевантен будет другой вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/778985/203622 Из-за различий LVM/не-LVM не является дубликатом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если в нескольких словах:

1. сделайте бэкап диска с данными
2. создайте рэйд 1 из нового(он же пуст, верно?):

   **mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 missing /dev/sdb1**

должен получиться новый рейд в котором один диск отсутствует.
Если не получится - указываем --raid-devices=1

3. Используя live систему(для убунты можно режим recovery)/скопируйте всё с первого на второй с помощью dd(игонорируя ошибки)

   **dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/md0 bs=4096 conv=noerror,sync**

или

```
**cp -a /path_mount_old_disk/*  /path_mount_md0/**
```

4. на всякий случай обновите граб на /dev/sdb
5. отредактируйте fstab и загрузитесь с рэйда.
6. если всё ок: добавляем старый диск в рэйд:

   **mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sda**

6.1.  Если был указан --raid-devices=1, то сначала расширяем до 2:

```
**mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --raid-devices=2**
```

и повторяем команду из п.6. Следить за состоянием синхронизации можно:

```
**watch -n 0,1 'cat /proc/mdstat'**
```

7. Выполняем grub-install для второго диска
8. Контрольный ребут

Это "план". Детали могут меняться(обращаем внимание на имена дисков). 
Ещё раз - не забываем про бэкап ;)

Comment: Необходимо отметить, что для корректного переноса dd необходимо делать на отмонтированной файловой системе, либо как максимум на read-only. То есть из recovery режима или live cd. Попытка так делать на запущенной системе к хорошему не приведёт.

Comment: поправил ответ. спасибо!